# How can I make only the constrained box scrollable or any other kind of box for the given scenario

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

Current State of the problem

**UI:**

[Make this Yellow Boxes Scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uUDm.png)

**Code:**

[This is the Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHlAK.png)

How can I make only the yellow boxes... and keep the red box positioned as it is.

or any other alternative as I'm using a custom navigation container in the bottom and that cannot be scrolled.

Thank you.

Comment: Don't post [code-image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/10157127) instead include your code-snippet using format tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to below code

```
class YellowBox extends StatefulWidget {
  const YellowBox({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _YellowBoxState createState() => _YellowBoxState();
}

class _YellowBoxState extends State<YellowBox> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text("Hello World"),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        height: 80.0,
        width: ScreenUtil().screenWidth,
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 80.0,
            width: ScreenUtil().screenWidth,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 10,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, int index) {
                return Container(
                  margin:
                      EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 20.0),
                  height: 80.0,
                  width: 100.0,
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: result]